# How to find the highest median value in pandas data frame grouped by month?

Tags: python, pandas

Problem Statement: Which month has the highest median of maximum_gust_speed (thats name of the column) of all available records? Also print its value.

```
Day                          3280 non-null object
Average temperature (Â°F)    3280 non-null float64
Average gustspeed (mph)      3280 non-null float64
Maximum temperature (Â°F)    3280 non-null float64
Maximum gust speed (mph)     3280 non-null float64
```

Day has String type date like "dd/mm/yyyy".

My code:

```
ave = data.groupby(pd.DatetimeIndex(data['Day']).month)['Maximum gust speed (mph)'].median().reset_index(name='Median')

gust=ave['Median'].max()
max_gust_value = "{0:.2f}".format(ave['Median'].max())
mnth=ave[ave.Median==gust]['Day']
max_gust_month = mnth.values[0]
print(max_gust_value)
print(max_gust_month)
```

The answers are not matching the expected results. Expected month value should be 2 whereas it is 11 in my case. Please tell me what changes to make in the code.

Answer (score 1):

I have applied the below for the answer. Test this out and let me know. I believe this the climate dataset in your case as well.

First, create a Month column, in my case the months extracted were like eg - for January it came as '01'.

Post that a group by of Maximum gust speed (mph) and Month. And then extract your requirements, in my case I needed `max_gust_value` and `max_gust_month`. You can follow the same.

```py
df['Month'] = df['Day'].apply(lambda x:x.split('/')[1])

df_med_gust=df['Maximum gust speed (mph)'].groupby(df['Month']).median()

max_gust_value = df_med_gust[str(df_med_gust.idxmax())[:10]]
max_gust_month = df_med_gust.idxmax()[:10]
```